# date format to insert into database

Tags: mysql

my script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Description: Extract Lab data from text file and insert to database
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Modules Required
use DBI;  # check drivers


#print "vs2-001-001-ma-sampleFile\n";


my $filename = "vs2-001-001-ma-sampleFile.txt";   

my $count = 0 ;  #initialize variable $count
my ($paraval, $paraname, $pararange, $paraunit);  #initialise variables for parameters
#chomp($filename=<>);   #uncomment it To use keyboard input. and type filename with extension Ex: fileName.txt or fileName.csv

open (OUT,">>$filename.csv") || die print "No\t $!";
close OUT;

open (IN,"$filename") || die print "Noo Input. $!";
my @file=<IN>;

#join the lines with # dilimits
my $string = join('#', @file);

  $string =~s /[\r]//g; # To remove space. 
 $string =~s /[\n]//g;
 $string =~s /[\t]//g;  # To remove tab




# pattern under while loop will do the work. it will take date as 13 Oct 2010 in $1 and rest values in $2 
# $string=~/Equine Profile Plus\s+#(.*?\s+)\s+.*?(Sample.*)##/g

 while($string=~/Equine Profile Plus\s+#(.*?\s+)\s+.*?(Sample.*?)##/g){
 my($date,$line,$Sample_Type,$Patient_ID,$Sample_Id,$Doctor_Id,$Location,$Rotor,$Serial,$para,$QC,$HEM,$LIP,$ICT);
 $count++;

 my $date=$1;


 $line=$2;  
  if ($line=~/Sample Type:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Sample_Type=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Patient ID:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Patient_ID=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Sample ID:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Sample_Id=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Doctor ID:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Doctor_Id=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Location:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Location=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Rotor Lot Number:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Rotor=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/Serial Number:(.*?)#/gis){
   $Serial=clean($1);
  }if ($line=~/#(NA+.*?GLOB.*?)#/gis){

   $para=$1;
   $para =~ s/#/;/g;
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;   #remove spaces.
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;   
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;  
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;
   $para =~ s/\s\s/ /g;
   $para =~ s/ /:/g;

  if ($line=~/#QC(.*?) #HEM(.*?) LIP(.*?) ICT(.*?)  /gis){
   $QC=clean($1);
   $HEM=clean($2);
   $LIP=clean($3);
   $ICT=clean($4);
  }
  while($para =~ /(.*?):(.*?):(.*?);/g){
  $paraname = $1;
  $paraval = $2;
  $pararange = $3;
  #$paraunit = $4;    

  # convert the date into DBMS-FORMAT
  my %map = ( 'Jan' => '01' , 'Feb' => '02',  'Mar' => '03', 'Apr' => '04','May' => '05',
   'Jun' =>'06' ,'Jul'=>'07',
   'Aug'=>'08','Sep'=>'09','Oct'=>'10','Nov'=>'11','Dec'=>'12'  );

  if ( $date =~ m/(..).(...).(....)/ ) {
      my ( $d, $m, $y ) = ( $1, $2, $3 );
   $out = sprintf $y, $map{$m}, '%d-%02d-%d', $d;

  }
  else{
   die ;
  }
  print "Parsing the input ...\n"; 
  open (OUT,">>$filename.csv") || die print "No"; #data from text file written to a CSV file.
      print OUT "\"$count\",\"$out\",\"$Sample_Type\",\"$Patient_ID\",\"$Sample_Id\",\"$Doctor_Id\",\"$Location\",\"$Rotor\",\"$Serial\",\"$QC\",\"$HEM\",\"$LIP\",\"$ICT\",\"$paraname\",\"$paraval\",\"$pararange\",\n";
  }


  }




 }
 close OUT;

 #Load csv into mysql
 print "\n inserting into database\n"; 
&loaddata('$filename.csv');  # comment it while not loading into the database.
 print "\n Database insert completed \n"; 
 sub clean
{
my ($line) = shift (@_);
$line =~ s/\n//g;
$line =~ s/\r//g;
$line =~ s/^\s+//g; 
$line =~ s/\s\s//g;
$line =~ s/\s+$//g;
$line =~ s/#//g;
return ($line);
}



#init the mysql DB
sub init_dbh{

$db="";
$host="";
$user="";
$password="";

my $dbh   = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:database=$db:host=$host",
                          $user,
                          $password)
                          or die "Can't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

       return $dbh;

}

#Load data to mysql table
sub loaddata{
        my ($name) = @_;
        my $DBH = init_dbh( );
        my $STH_GO = $DBH->prepare(q{
                LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'vs2-001-001-ma-sampleFile.txt.csv' INTO TABLE parameter FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; })or die "ERROR: ".    $DBI::errstr;
        $STH_GO->execute();

        }
```

this gives the date format in CSV file as 13-10-2010 but when inserting into database gives 0000-00-00..please help me in modifying the script.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in MySQL are specified as YYYY-MM-DD, not DD-MM-YYYY.  Adjust the output to match this format.

Comment: how to change the format...i have no clue..should change in mysql section??

Comment: You need to change the format that your script generates.  Alter your sprintf call.  Incidentally, I'm not sure how the call you have is actually working the way you describe, since the template string should be supplied as the first argument, not the third.  You probably want something like: sprintf '%04d-%02d-%02d', $y, $map{$m}, $d

Comment: i tried doing this way....                                        my %map = ( 'Jan' => '01' , 'Feb' => 

'02',  'Mar' => '03', 'Apr' => '04','May' => '05',
   

'Jun' =>'06' ,'Jul'=>'07',
   

'Aug'=>'08','Sep'=>'09','Oct'=>'10','Nov'=>'11','Dec'=>'12'  );
 
 

 if ( $date =~ m/(..).(..).(......)/ ) {
      

my ( $d, $m, $y) = ( $1, $2, $3 );
   $out 

= sprintf  '%04d-%02d-%02d', $y, $map{$m}, $d ;
   
  }
  else{
   

die ;
  }                                                                   but my output is 2010-00-13..n not 2010-10-13

Comment: Your regular expression only captures two characters for the month, but you are attempting to map from 3 characters to a number.  You will need to modify that expression to capture the date correctly.  A sample of the date format would help.